# Surefire fails to generate full stack trace of failed tests in surefire reports

Tags: maven, unit-testing, stack-trace, maven-surefire-plugin

I have changed the surefire "trimStackTrace" to false to get the full stacktrace of test failures but the generated reports only have stack trace for some of the tests. I use junit 4.12 and maven surefire "3.0.0-M5". For example, for two tests in the same class (package cc.mallet), I have these two results as below. In test 13, I have the full trace but for test 16 I do not have it. Is it possible to have the full stack traces of failed tests in the generated surefire-reports?
test 13:

```
 java.lang.AssertionError
    **at cc.mallet.types.FeatureSequence.add(FeatureSequence.java:129)
    at cc.mallet.types.FeatureSequence.<init>(FeatureSequence.java:48)**
    at cc.mallet.types.HashedSparseVector_ESTest.test13(HashedSparseVector_ESTest.java:559)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.FailOnTimeout$CallableStatement.call(FailOnTimeout.java:288)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.FailOnTimeout$CallableStatement.call(FailOnTimeout.java:282)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

'''
test 16:
'''

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<1.0> but was:<1825.52014>
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:89)
    at org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:835)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:555)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:685)
    at cc.mallet.types.HashedSparseVector_ESTest.test16(HashedSparseVector_ESTest.java:735)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.FailOnTimeout$CallableStatement.call(FailOnTimeout.java:288)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.FailOnTimeout$CallableStatement.call(FailOnTimeout.java:282)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

test 16 is full stack trace.

If you do not want to trim the stack trace by the plugin, set [trimStackTrace to false](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#trimStackTrace).

Comment: Because in test 16 I do not have my package name among lines, I think it is not a full stack trace, in comparison with test 13. I also set trimStackTrace to false to get the above result.

Comment: Pls create some prototype project on GitHub. The Apache team can debug only a real code. And then we will fix it. Thx